# Can i get multiple files from spring cloud server into .net application?

Tags: c#, .net, spring, cloud, steeltoe

I am wondering is it possible to load not only appconfig.json from spring config server but other files. For example i have got a templates in .html format. Can I somehow get them from spring server along with appsettings file? Probably steeltoe knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steeltoe does provide a configuration provider for Spring Cloud Config Server that will allow you to map configuration values from any supported file format into key-value pairs, and there are several strategies for layering multiple configuration files but I don't think there would be any support for .html files.

If you're looking for a way to use version-controlled templates, why not read from a git repo directly rather than putting config server in the middle?